# NSTreeController: KVO for custom property keypath fails.

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, key-value-observing, nstreecontroller

## The Setup

I have an `NSTreeController` subclass. It has a property called `selectedProject` which is custom and declared like this in the header:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) LPProject *selectedProject;
```

And like this in the private implementation:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) LPProject *selectedProject;
```

Critically, at EVERY point where I modify `selectedProject` in my TreeController, I go through the generated setter/getters. I never modify the iVar directly.

Basically, the reason this property exists is because the normal `selectedObjects` and `selection` properties of `NSTreeController` aren't typed and since I know this TreeController will ALWAYS manage only LPProject objects AND that only a single project can ever be selected at once, I wanted a nice clean iVar to use, rather than constantly getting the selectedObjects, checking if there is one, taking the first object in the array, etc.

---

#### LPProject

`LPProject` is a custom `NSManagedObject` subclass from Core Data. It has a property named `enabled`. This property is a BOOL, represented by an NSNumber. The getters/setters for it are generated by Xcode.

---

#### The Issue

In several controllers, I attempt to watch the `enabled` property of the `selectedProject` object, like this:

```
[_myTreeController addObserver:self 
                    forKeyPath:@"selectedProject.enabled" 
                       options:0 
                       context:NULL];
```

I have verified that the KVO notification arrives when `selectedProject` changes (and, as a result, `selectedProject.enabled` changes). HOWEVER, when *only* the `enabled` property of `selectedProject` changes (that is, the selected project itself remains the same), the KVO notification does not arrive.

HOWEVER, if I instead subscribe this way:

```
[_myTreeController addObserver:self 
                    forKeyPath:@"selection.enabled" 
                       options:0 
                       context:NULL];
```

It works perfectly. When `enabled` changes and `selectedProject` remains the same, the KVO notification arrives.

I am confused by this, because `selectedProject` is KVO-compliant and I feel like the keypath to `.enabled` should work.

Can anyone shed light on this? What have I missed?

Comment: How do you update `selectedProject`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how and when are you updating the `selectedProject` property, however since the `selection`-based approach works as expected (and not only for this), I recommend you make the `selectedProject` a derived property from `selectedObjects` (as `selection` is a proxy, and `selectedObjects` is KVO too):

```
// tell Cocoa which property changes directly affect selectedProject
+ (NSSet*)keyPathsForValuesAffectingSelectedProject {
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"selectedObjects"];
}

- (LPProject*)selectedProject {
    // you might need to do some isKindOfClass checks if not all nodes are LPProject
    return self.selectedObjects.first;
}
```

The header property declaration stays the same, the implementation declaration is not needed if you provide the setter.

The beauty of this is that the runtime will automatically send KVO notifications for the `selectedProject` property when `selectedObjects` change, with minimum of glue code.